# In Android, how do I send different types of push notification from the same app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In Android, when you get the same type of push notification, the most recent one replaces the previous one in your notification screen, mostly likely to prevent clutter. However, I saw that in some apps, I get separate notifications from the same app that do not replace the previous notification. How do I program my app to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for having multiple notifications on the status bar, all you have to do is set a unique notification ID for every notification you want. If you send two notifications with the same ID, the notification manager replaces the oldest one with the newest. Have a look in [Notification Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)'s notify method.

Here's an example of how to send a notification:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Make sure `notificationId` is unique, otherwise it'll replace the oldest notification with the same ID.

Comment: @user2911983 - was it helpful?